# Multiple forms in one django template

Tags: django

I have a django template that has 2 forms. Each form submits to different models, and each form has one field to populate. The two models are:

1. Coverletter
2. Snippits

My page allows users to add content to the coverletter via form and click submit, which will populate the content field in the coverletter model. On the same html page / template, the user can add content to snippits via form and click submit, which will populate the body field in the snippit model.

I am using 2 views:

1. CoverLetterUpdateView, which uses django built in UpdateView
2. SnippitCreateView, which uses django built in CreateView

**The problem**
I cannot get each form to populate their own models. They both only populate the coverletter model. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong and cannot seem to find an answer online. I've been stuck at this for a couple days now. I'm sure I am missing something obvious like naming the forms different, but I cannot seem to figure out how to solve this. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
#urls.py

path(
    route='coverletter/<int:pk>/new/',
    view=CoverletterCreateContentView.as_view(),
    name='coverletter-create-content'
),
path(
    route='snippits/new/,
    view=SnippitCreateView.as_view(),
    name=snippit-create
),





#views.py

class CoverletterUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Coverletter
    fields = ['content']
    template_name = 'cl/cl_create_content.html'

class SnippitCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Snippit
    fields = ['snippit_text']
    template_name = 'cl/snippit_create_form.html'



#models.py

class Snippit(models.Model):
    snippit_text = models.TextField

class Coverletter(models.Model):
    content = HTMLField() #this is a tinymce field


#html
#cl/cl_create_content.html
#This is the first form for the coverletter
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        {{ form|crispy | safe }}
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>

#This is the second form for snippit
<form method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <fieldset class="form-group">
       <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Snippit</legend>
       {{ form|crispy | safe }}
   </fieldset>
   <div class="form-group">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Create Snippit</button>
   </div>
```

Comment: @Melvyn I've updated with some of the code. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Just as I thought. You're not using 2 views. You're only using one view. You've defined 2 views, but only use 1 in the urls.py. So the other one is not hooked up to anything. Second, you HTML <form> tag must get an action attribute for the snippet view url, once you've hooked it up.

Comment: @Melvyn I've added another Route above. I can get the snippit form working to submit but only on it's own html page. What I am trying to do is have both forms show on one html page and the user can submit either form, which would populate their own models. I am still confused on how to solve this.